# I am trying to instantiate XSSFWorkbook, Java throws ClassNotFoundException(cn) (ONLY IN DEBUG)

Tags: java, dependencies, apache-poi, classnotfoundexception, xssf

when I try to instantiate XSSFWorkbook Java throws ClassNotFoundException(cn)

cn value is =  "org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager"

my code is like this:

```java
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

String filePath = "C://fakename.xlsx"

if(Files.exists(Paths.get(filePath))) { 
    FileInputStream fis = null; 
    try { 
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 

    }
              
    XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    
    try { 
                  
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
              
}
```

as you may understand I have no problem importing that class or calling it in the code (I can see suggestions by auto-complete (intellisense))

[image]

**these are the dependencies**

I am not a Java developer, Im doing my own researches, tried to change dependencies but nothing yet,
in an old project I did use this and I never had a problem.

can someone of you give me some hints, please?

thank you

EDIT: this problem happens only in debugging, it's like if there is a breakpoint in this exception.

[image]

but, if I disable it, I can not debug my software anymore.

so weird.

Comment: unrelated to your question: you don't need poi-examples, poi-integration and probably not poi-excelant. if you just do XSSF stuff, there's a whole bunch of other dependencies to get rid of - see component map at http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html

Comment: thank you a lot, Kiwiwings, I will get rid of these jars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your development environment also suggests code completion the correct jar must be loaded.
Probably your execution environment does not load all the needed jars.
In this case the poi-5.0.0.jar and the poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar must be loaded. The org.apache.poi.xssf package is located in the poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar file.

If you make sure that this jar is loaded at execution then everything should be fine. So check your classpath settings in your execution environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am sure jar are loaded, but now I noticed that if I do not debug my application it just works, when I debug my application it stops on that kind of exception ( no breakpoints), it seems an Eclipse problem.